# How to prove that total magnetic field is vector sum of magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, superposition

How can we show that $\vec B_{tot}= \sum \vec B_i$?
In case of electric field It can be easily shown from that forces adds vectorially
, which can be shown from fact that displacements adds vectorically.

$$\vec F_{tot}=\sum \vec F_i=\sum \vec E_i q_s=q_s \sum \vec E_i=q_s \vec E_{tot} $$
so $$\vec E_{tot}=\sum \vec E_i$$

So we can try to do similar to prove that  magetic fields adds vectorically.
First of all
$$\vec F_i=q \vec v \times \vec B_i$$, so
$$\vec F_{tot}=\sum \vec F_i=\sum q \vec v \times \vec B_i=q \vec v \times \sum \vec B_i=q \vec v \times \vec B_{tot}$$
But here as far I understand we can't infer that
$$\vec B_{tot}=\sum \vec B_i$$
Or can we? So, how to show that we can add up magnetic fields like vectors?

Comment: If you write $\vec F_i=q \vec v \times \vec B_i$, you have already established that the magnetic field is a vector.

Comment: I was afraid you say that. I am not convinced. I believe we can prove that. I established that $\vec B_i$ is a vector, but I didn't established that $\sum \vec B_i=\vec B_{tot}$.

Comment: Instead of saying "prove that", you might say "show that the mag field is consistent with identification as a vector".  I think that the concern of @GiorgioP doesn't apply, but you get what you want.

Comment: @garyp If one doesn't know that the magnetic field is a vector, the cross product can not be used and $q \vec v \times magnetic~field~$ is not defined. If we know that it is a vector, there is nothing to prove.

Comment: GiorgioP. Your argument doesn't convince me. As far I understand we can look at theory in two ways: idealistically of materialistically. I wanted proof that suits for materialist. J. Murrary's answer fully satisfied me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But here as far I understand we can't infer that $\vec B_{tot} = \sum_i \vec B_i$

Why do you think this?  If $q \vec v \times \sum \vec B_i=q \vec v \times \vec B_{tot}$, then $q\vec v \times \left(\vec B_{tot}-\sum_i \vec B_i\right) = 0$.  Since this holds for any $\vec v$, the quantity in brackets must vanish.

> Could you explain how to prove your statement using predicate logic and axioms or well-known theorems of vector algebra.

The statement is that if $\vec A \times \vec B = 0$ for all $\vec A$, then $\vec B = 0$.  The proof is essentially trivial - let $\{\hat x,\hat y,\hat z\}$ be the standard unit vectors, and let $\vec A = \hat x$.  Then
$$\hat x \times \vec B  = -B_z \hat y + B_y \hat z = 0 \implies B_z = B_y = 0$$
Repeating the process with $\vec A = \hat y$ or $\hat z$ shows that $B_x=0$ as well.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. So we have $q \vec v \times (\vec B_{tot}-\sum \vec B_i)$=0, how can we infer from that $\vec B_{tot}=\sum \vec B_i$?

Comment: @AlexAlex If $\vec v \times\left(\vec B_{tot}-\sum \vec B_i\right)=0$ for every $\vec v$, then that implies that $\vec B_{tot}-\sum \vec B_i = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I learned predicate logic myself, I prefer Fitch notation. I am chemist and I had calculus I and  II course, I solved every problem about linear algebra in my textbook and I know very well my calculus I and II textbook. Could you explain how to prove your statement using predicate logic and axioms or well-known theorems of vector algebra. Or can you address me to textbook where your inference is described?

Comment: @AlexAlex I have updated my answer with an explanation.